# PDO prepared function issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble getting this to work I think my error is in the syntax of the prepared statement but I have tried several different methods with no luck. The reason I suspect that the error is in the prepared statement is because it will `echo Not a Match` on the page if the variables dont match but when they do match it will just give me a blank page with no errors. Here is my code maybe someone can spot the error in the mean time I will keep trying different methods.

```
    function setPass($conn, $userCurrent, $oldPass, $newPass, $verPass)

{        
    $stmt= $conn->prepare('SELECT `password` FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`=:userCurrent');
    $stmt->execute(array(':userCurrent' => $userCurrent));
    while ($pass = $stmt->fetch()){
    $oldDbPass = $pass['password'];
    }

$new_pass = md5($newPass);

    if (md5($oldPass) == ($oldDbPass) && ($newPass) == ($verPass)) {
try{
        $stmt= $conn->prepare('UPDATE `CLL_users` SET `password`=:newPass WHERE `user_name`=:userCurrent');
        $stmt->execute(array(':newpass' => $new_pass, ':userCurrent' => $userCurrent));
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

        echo "Match";
    } else {
        echo "Not a Match";

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaking parenthesis for backticks.  Use backticks "`"  to escape table and column names in SQL.

```
SELECT `password` FROM `CLL_users` WHERE `user_name`=:userCurrent

UPDATE `CLL_users` SET `password`=:newPass WHERE `user_name`=:userCurrent
```

You also have several typos:

- `$newPass` is declared as camelCase, but used as `$new_pass` in your second `execute` statement.
- I'm not sure if PDO statements are case sensitive, but you're declaring the PDO variable as `:newPass` and using it as `:newpass` in the `execute`

For the future, read about error checking/handling in PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorcode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Ok I enabled the error handling and got this message `Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: I updated my code per your suggestion and edited my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: EXCELLENT!!!!! They are case sensitive I updated the `newpass` to `newPass` and it worked!! Thanks so much and the reason I have `new_pass` in the execute statement is because I encrypted the variable passed from the form so if you look there is a line `$new_pass = md5($newPass);` maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @Yamaha32088 I'm not sure about your question there, but it's not good to store passwords without a salt.  Here is [a good tutorial](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/247188-user-authentication-class/).

Comment: @Daedalus thanks for the link I will take a look at it I am new to PHP so I am still in the learning stages I just wanted to get this working  I'm stating simple and working my way into more difficult things as I progress

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new to something.  Everyone was once.  It's great to see you improving yourself and your code.  +1